# Using USB or ethernet to carry digital signals

Tags: ethernet

I need to send six digital signals about 4 feet through wires. An ethernet cable has 8 little wires that should do the trick. I could split the ends and solder them to my boards.

Is there an adaptor that will let me plug in the ethernet cable cable to my board and have access to the signal from each wire on a pin? If not, can I accomplish this through USB? Is there a more elegant solution than having six long wires?

Comment: You mean like a RJ-45 jack?

Comment: 10BaseT cables have 4 twisted pairs.  USB cables have 4 wires, 2 for signal and 2 for power.  Careful how long you make the wire.  High speed digital signals like ones that a processor can make can not go far with out special attention.

Comment: something like https://www.ebay.nl/itm/Kit-RJ45-8-pin-Connector-and-Breakout-Board-For-Cat5-Cat5e-Cat6-Ethernet-Cables/131857340868 . Don't forget that you also need one wire for the GND connection.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams do you know of one that has pins at a right angle that can go down into a breadboard?

Comment: @Gerben perfect make that your answer I will accept it

Comment: @Gerben for bonus points which one carries the +/gnd for POE?